# Windows and Windows Forms

Tags: c, wpf, winapi, window

I need a window to receive/handle messages from a driver. Will creating a Windows Form in visual studio be same as creating window? Will the windows form do the thing I am trying to do?

What is the difference between windows form and window? Or Even WPF, does it suit my purpose or are windows/windows forms and wfp totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need a window to receive/handle messages from a driver. Will creating a Windows Form in visual studio be same as creating window? Will the windows form do the thing I am trying to do?

Yes, basically it will be the same. I think this article answers your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxxy49h(v=vs.80).aspx

> With Windows Forms you develop smart clients. Smart clients are
>   graphically rich applications that are easy to deploy and update, can
>   work when they are connected to or disconnected from the Internet, and
>   can access resources on the local computer in a more secure manner
>   than traditional Windows-based applications.

And about the difference between WPF and WinForms you can read in this CodeProject#s article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25795/Creating-the-Same-Program-in-Windows-Forms-and-WPF

Comment: Can I create a window only in VS or are there other softwares that you know of? I started creting Both WPF and Windows form in VS and they have strange coding and no .c,.cpp, or .cs file. I want plain old .c or .h files for windows applications. Any suggestions

Comment: You don't need any other software besides Visul Stuio, even VS Express Edition will do it. I would use C# .NET (*.cs files): forget the old *.c files!

Comment: Yes but that creates a project file and I cannot see the file with the window functions like WindProc, WindMain. I need to define functions withing these.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, HTH: http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/random.htm . It pays off to become familiar with C #, believe me!